# Every k dimensional subspace U of K^n is solving space of a homogenous linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The question:

"Let $K$ be a vector space. Show, that every $k$-dimensional subspace $U$ is a solution space of a homogenous linear system of equations $Ax$=$0$ for an $m$ x $n$ Matrix $A$.What is the minimal value of $m$?"

There is a remark, to use the mapping $K^n$ $\mapsto$ $K^n/U$.

Now I know that the solution space is defined as $ker F$ so I have to show that the kernel of $F$ has $k$ dimensions.  So I look at $F:K^n$ $\mapsto$ $K^m$. We know that $U \subseteq Ker F$.
Is the kernel here unique? We know that k has to be $k=n-r$ where $r$ is the rank of $A$. I do not see how that affects $m$ of $A$.   Can I approach this using a commutative diagramm with

$K^n \xrightarrow{F} K^m $

$\downarrow$  $ \begin{array}{1} \end{array}$     $\nearrow$

$K^n/U$

and if yes how does the commutativity of this diagramm answer the question?

Comment: Did you mean $n=\text{dim}(K)$ ?

Comment: extend a bases of U to a bases of  V and use the dual bases?